# Java StringTemplate boolean parameter

Tags: java, stringtemplate

How do you pass a boolean argument? I have a method that needs to take in a boolean `true/false` to render depending whether or not it is set.

I tried `<list(true)>` (also `TRUE`, `false`, `FALSE`) and all gave something like `no such attribute: FALSE`

Passing 0/1 doesn't work (i.e. `<if(0)>` came out as true)

Something like this:

```
list(next) ::= <<
SELECT * FROM users

<if(next)>
WHERE Id \< (SELECT Id FROM users)
<endif>

ORDER BY Id DESC
LIMIT :limit;
>>


getList() ::= <<
<list(false)>;
>>
```

Comment: Please include the whole fragment to see which arguments does your method expect.

Comment: @Alfabravo added

Comment: This doesn't look like Java to me.  What language is it?

Comment: This is StringTemplate file